# Is it safe to use C++'s std::move from object in inner scope to outer scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the following C++11/14 code snippet I use `std::move` to
"move" the contents of the vector `Y` in the inner scope, to the vector `X`
in outer scope:

```
void foo() {
   vector<int> X(10);
   ...
   for (...) {
      vector<int> Y(100);
      ...
      X = std::move(Y);
   }
   ...Safe to use X here which contains Y's last content?
 }
```

`Y`'s contructor/destructor is invoked at the top/bottom of the loop for each iteration. Since the contents are "moved" out of `Y` to `X` those contents will still be viable (now stored in `X`) beyond the end of the loop correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, vector follows value semantics.

The storage is now owned by the outer vector, after a move.

Comment: Thanks. Sanity check -- that's what I thought.

Comment: @remy The correctness of the OP's code does not require move semantics (that would be sufficient as well).  If there is an actual error in my interpretaation, please clarify.